# Unable to find the specified file when publishing application

Tags: vb.net, mp3, publish, ioexception

I have a vb.net application which plays a mp3, but once I publish it the file cannot be found. I get the following error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.

```
Public Class Form2
Public audio As New AudioFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\01 - Help.mp3")
Public Sub startsong(ByVal D As Data)
    Me.Show()
    MHTvalue.Text = D.mht.ToString
    Maxcallsvalue.Text = D.maxcalls
    CPHvalue.Text = D.cph
    If Form1.playsong = True Then
        audio.Play()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Me.Close()
    audio.Stop()
    Form1.waittimer = 180000
End Sub

End Class
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you store the file? Do you have it in the solution and copy it to output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

I didn't have set as content in build action for the mp3 file